# making shifts in visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

this is my first question in this helpful website ..
I am working on a system for a pharmacy , using visual studio , writing by vb.net . I want to make shifts for pharmacist and save their shifts in data base , I want when the user (pharmacist) log in to the system , shift No. and user name and date and time upper in form . And when the user log out , I want system to save all that details , and save the No. of hours in a coloumn .. I can't save the No. of hourse , i tried to use the timer but it didn't work !! so can u help me to make shifts in my system ..

Comment: Can you save other data, though? If all you can't save is the number of hours... Store the entry time and exit time as DateTimes. In .NET, if you subtract one DateTime from another (A - B), the result is a variable of the TimeSpan type, which represents the time the worker has been in. Hope it helps. Your question'll probably be closed due to poor quality (you didn't show any code, and it does look like you're asking us to code for you).

Comment: Specifically what did you try and in what way did it not work?  We're not really here to write the application for you, but we'll gladly help you fix a problem that's blocking you.

Comment: @ranan & david sorry if I make some mistake in my guestion , cuz it is the first time + I didn't know that I must write code & I didn't want you to write the application , I started in this code , where should I write the code for you ? can I write it in another comment ? sorry again & thanks for help ..

Comment: *question
*@Renan
*@David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make database column with datetime field .. for example you name it `"Login_hour"` and `"Logout_Hour"`

In VB you may store current time like this

```
DataTable.Rows(n).Item("Login_Time") = now()
```

When logout ..

```
DataTable.Rows(n).Item("Logout_Time") = now()
```

Then you will get time different

```
Dim Work_Time as TimeSpan = DataTable.Rows(n).Item("Logout_Time") - DataTable.Rows(n).Item("Login_Time")
```

So you can use `Format(Work_Time.Hours) & ":" & format(Work_Time.Minutes)` to display work_time

Comment: yes , This is a good Idea that to save the of log in in a column & the time of log out on a column , but if I can take the number of hours & save it in one column & call it for example "the time " it is easy for manager , but if I can't do that , I will use your way .. thanks for you ..

Comment: so you say to save the time in the column when the user log in , and when he log out save the time in the other column ?

Comment: can I vote two answer ? I think voting is like saying it is good answer even if it isn't the exactly the best answer , so I vote your answer first and vote his answer & I didn't know the vote was going from you , sorry I am a newbie ..

Comment: ok , now I didn't vote for anyone ..
If you can found the what I need tell me ..

Comment: I understand what you said & I think before In this way , but I want to do it by another way , & if I couldn't find it , I will do as you say ..
instead of two column in DB (login_hour & logout_hour ) I want one column , & I want to find the method which make me find the number of hours & aftr that I it in that column , but I didn't find that method , I write "timer1.start" & "timer1.stop" so I need a method take the number of hours in timer1 ..

Comment: @musaab : my answer is updated .. such a basic idea

Comment: that may be work for me :) but last qustions : did I need to read from table , can I save the login_time in a variable & the logout_time in a variable & for example make (z = a-b) & save z in a database ?
+ how I can save this time in a variable ?

Comment: @musaab : Since you have data login_time and logout_time you dont have to store working_time .. you can do it in runtime ..

Answer (score 0):

From experience I would suggest using ASP MVC for this kind of application, as each user on their computer would still have access to the Application. I do this as i can get the user name from the AD - or even local PC, and manipulate it in any way - as you need to save it in a database!

Another benefit would be the use of the Modules, which you can design to save to a database, and call up on it. Still all in VB mind - but it’s all very powerful stuff!

You could also generate a sytem based timer, so when a button is clicked it logs the time, or intiates a count up to be stored in the session. Then set to the DB.

Again this is all personally, but would definately suit this kind of application.

Comment: I can't use ASP MVC because I work on a local system , I used the timer form the tool box and I wrote in the log in button "timer1.start" and in the log out button "timer1.stop" , & I try to take the time between log in & log out but I didn't find the method which do that !!!
thanks for your answer ..